What is the proper configuration and command to run bitcoincore and use RPC over LAN?
So, I'm trying to setup my node on a small computer I have lying around and, for practical reasons, I want to be able to do RPC requests to it from computers within my own LAN. Specifically I'm running it on an ubuntu machine and trying to send requests from a windows machine.
I've found 2 questions already here and here and I did attempt their answers, but they didn't work.
As far as I can tell, curl is connecting successfully to the server. It prompts me for the RPC password, but then I get no response back.
What I've tried so far
Running bitcoind with:
bitcoind -rpcbind=0.0.0.0 -rpcallowip=192.168.1.0/24

I get:
EDIT: I later found out that, in windows, I should use curl.exe to use the same curl as in linux. I still get the same results
PS C:\Users\Mateus> curl.exe --user ceuta --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id": "curltest", "method":"getblockchaininfo", "params": []}' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://192.168.0.8:8332/

PS C:\Users\Mateus>

If I set these values in bitcoin.conf, I get the same results. If I do the curl command from a terminal session in the node machine, using the 127.0.0.1 ip, I get the response back.
Alternatively, if I specify rpcbind to be 192.168.0.8 (my node's computer ip address), I get the same behavior, except that in the node's machine now I also don't get the response.
I'm sorry if this might actually be more of a networking question, but I'm just wondering what is a standard way to configure one's node to be able to do RPC requests from other machines on the same LAN and if there are any configuration prerequisites for the machines like firewalls, static ips or whatever, pointing me to a resource would be quite helpful too...

Is it possible you have a firewall on the server, or your router, which blocks port 8332?

Yeah. I actually also have made sure this wasn't a firewall issue. Now, I'm unsure wether its the router. I did try to setup port forwarding, just to be 100% sure (I found nothing mentioning it was blocking anything) but my provider configured it so I can't add port forwarding rules. So now that's where I'm heading....

I'm leaving this as the answer merely to have the question marked as done.
First thing: the questions I linked to and what I described as my node configuration are indeed the correct configuration to have a node accept RPC requests over a network.
My issue was that my router seemed to be interfering. I'm unsure how this should work but 2 things lead me to believe this is true:

The router's configuration had port forwarding turned off. I guess this is the evidence with the least force since it also mentions this is needed to forward requests from the public internet. But hey, it was the only thing that I could remotely relate to something blocking requests between computers in my LAN.
I just made a VPN using tailscale and my RPC requests just worked. And since against facts there can be no arguments, that pretty much settles it in my mind.

Unfortunately, my ISP thinks I'm not allowed to reconfigure these settings, for my own "safety". In other words, I need to get a different router. One that I control.
So to future readers, the advice is: check your router and use a VPN like tailscale. You even get the benefit of not having to be in your LAN to use your node.
